# Vector Subscript Out of Range While Trying to Populate a Struct with a Vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, range, subscript

I've rewritten this program more times than I'd care to admit, and I'm willing to do it again if someone could help me. I have a program that utilizes a .csv file to pull information about 1343 marathon runners into a vector. And then from the vector to a struct so that I can sort it based on things such as age, gender, etc. Here is what I have so far:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream";
#include "fstream";
#include "string";
#include "cstring";
#include "cmath";
#include "iomanip";
#include "cassert";
#include "cstdlib";
#include "ctime";
#include "cctype";
#include "algorithm";
#include "sstream";
#include "time.h";
#include "vector";

using namespace std;

struct runner{
    int position;
    string time;
    int age;
    string sex;
    string gender;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string city;
    string state;

};
int main(){

vector<runner> r;
  int i = 0;
  string counter;
  int holder = 0;

  string header;

  ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\cmarathon.csv");

  if (infile.is_open()) {
    getline( infile, header );
    cout<<header;

    while (getline(infile, counter)){
        holder++;
    }

    r.push_back(r[holder]);

    for (i = 0; i <= holder; i++){

        string dataChunk;
        int value;



        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        value = atoi(dataChunk.c_str());
        r[i].position = value;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].time = dataChunk;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        value = atoi(dataChunk.c_str());
        r[i].age = value;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].sex = dataChunk;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].gender = dataChunk;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].firstName = dataChunk;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].lastName = dataChunk;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].city = dataChunk;

        getline(infile, dataChunk, ',');
        r[i].state  = dataChunk;}

  }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
  }
```

I am extremely new to vectors and I just can't figure out what the problem is. I thought that by using push_back right before the for() loop I would have enough slots open? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When `r` is an empty vector (which it is at the beginning of `main`), `r[holder]` is invalid for any value of `holder`. The statement `r.push_back(r[holder]);` makes no sense - what is it supposed to achieve?

Comment: holder receives a value of ~1343 from the while loop just before the for loop. I thought by using push_back() I could allocate the space to {r}. Could I simply fix this by waiting to initialize the vector until after I have already gotten a line count?

Comment: You are likely looking for `vector::resize`

Comment: That looks to be what I need. But I'm still having trouble implementing it. I tried "r.resize(holder)" to hopefully resize it to the proper length, but I'm still faced with the same error. I think it has something to do with how my for() loop adds data to the structure. Could that be it?                      Edit: I was able to get it working by resizing to holder+1. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector `r` has no element with index `holder` So the statement below

```
r.push_back(r[holder]);
```

is wrong. Maybe you mean the following

```
r.resize( holder );
```

Also this loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= holder; i++){
```

has to look like

```
for (i = 0; i < holder; i++){
```

that is i has to be less than holder

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of small issues... below I provide a cleaned-up version for the first 4 fields.  Some notes:

- you don't need to presize the `vector`... if you `push_back` it will automatically resize transparently and reasonably efficiently (i.e. in increasingly large steps) to accommodate the extra elements
- you generally want the ongoing success of the field input commands to control the while loop, which populates a single `runner` object that is then `push_back`-ed to the `vector`

  - attemped further operations on a stream in an error state will harmlessly fail
  - a stream in an error state will evaluate `false` in a boolean evaluation context (e.g. `while` or `if` condition)
- you can use `>>` for numbers to parse in and consume a number
- use `getline()` to read all but the trailing comma into a string, dropping that comma from the stream
- I've provided a "helper" function `eat()` that eats commas... crucially it sets the input stream to a failure state if the comma wasn't read

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct runner
{
    int position;
    string time;
    int age;
    string sex;
};

template <char C = ','>
std::istream& eat(std::istream& is)
{
    char c;
    if (!(is >> c && c == C))
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return is;
}


int main()
{
    std::istringstream in("12, 4:45, 45, M\n"   // sample input - change to your file
                          "8, 3:46, 33, F\n");
    std::vector<runner> runners;

    runner r;
    while (in >> r.position)
        if (in >> eat &&
            getline(in, r.time, ',') &&
            in >> r.age >> eat >> r.sex)
            runners.push_back(r);
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "error in data for position " << r.position << '\n';
            exit(1);
        }

    // ...  use runners ...
}
```

You can then use the vector as in:

```
    // output all ages...
    for (auto& r : runners)
        std::cout << runners.age << '\n';

    // resort by age...
    std::sort(std::begin(runners), std::end(runners),
              [](const runner& x, const runner& y) { return x.age < y.age; }
    );
```